# Calling a recursive directory search using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am using the following snippet to remove CRLF from a file.
Is there a way to call this file to remove all CRLF from each file if I specify a directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion 
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%1) do ( 
    set /P "=%%a"< NUL )
)>%2
```

I have many directories below the root directory with multiple files in each.

Comment: Still quite stuck here. If anyone has an answer it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an outer `for /r "%~1" %%I in (*.mask)` loop, and change your `for /F` loop to act on `%%I`.  In a cmd console, type `help for` for more information.  Here, see if this works:

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem // for each .txt file recursively in source:
for /R "%~1" %%I in (*.txt) do (

    rem // get relative path + filename of %%I
    set "relative=%%I" & set "relative=!relative:%~1=!"

    rem // create relative directory structure in destination
    for %%a in ("%~2\!relative!") do md "%%~dpa" 2>NUL

    rem // for each line of src, output without line break to dest
    (
        for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~fI") do ( 
            set /P "=%%a"< NUL
        )
    ) >"%~2\!relative!"
)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back. Thanks for the reply. I tried to use this by trying this on the command line c:\temp c:\test but it is not working as I expected. I thought that the files from c:\temp and the directories below would be stripped and copied to c:\test .. is this what the above does ?

Comment: The above, if called as `batfile c:\temp c:\test`, will recursively search `c:\temp` for `*.txt`.  For each result, it will append the contents without line breaks to a file called `test` with no extension in the `c:\ ` root directory.  If this is not the behavior you wanted, please edit your question above and clarify your intentions.  Explain what you intend `>%2` to do in your example script.

Comment: I have no idea how to edit the original post. It is not intuitive (not for me anyway). I thought my question was fairly explanatory but to spell it out. I have a directory with lots of files and subdirectories in it. I need to remove all the CRLF from those files. I need to maintain the original file structure. The original example uses the syntax batchfile textfile.txt newtext.txt. This is fine if you have one file but I have hundreds in multiple directories so this is not really going to be quick. If I could just do something like batchfile c:\myfiles\*.* c:\mystrippedfiles\*.*

Comment: @Spitfire Very well.  See whether the updated solution does what you want.

Comment: Thank you rojo. You have it I think. It is doing exactly what I want. There are a few errors on the output though. For some reason it says "the syntax of the command is incorrect" it reapeats this about 6 times in the cmd window when I type in batch.bat c:\temp c:\output. Otherwise it seems to do exactly what I want. Thank you thank you thank you. I would have never figured this out by myself.